# How to read all files in a directory with spark_read_json from sparklyr

Tags: json, r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have json events stored locally (for debug) with this structure : `events/year/month/day/hour/somefiles.log`. Each `file.log` is file with on each line a json object (my event).

How I can load this files recursively with `spark_read_json` from the package sparklyr.
I tried :

```
library(sparklyr)

sc = spark_connect(master = "local")
events = spark_read_json(sc = sc, name = "events", path = "events/*")
```

but without success.

#### Edit 1

In fact it works at a certain level in the path for example

`events = spark_read_json(sc = sc, name = "events", path = "events/year/month/day/*")` works but

`events = spark_read_json(sc = sc, name = "events", path = "events/year/month/*"` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to specify the depth of the path search with multiple wildcards. Try:

```
events = spark_read_json(sc = sc, name = "events", path = "events/year/month/*/*")
```